# Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial ch 10.3.3: undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

Stuck on chapter 10 Hartl's tutorial. Have errors:

```
  1)
<pre>Micropost pages micropost creation with invalid information should not create a micropost
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button "Post" }.not_to change(Micropost, :count)
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb__934824114_93581680'
     # ./app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___342719359_93055030'
     # ./app/controllers/concerns/microposts_controller.rb:10:in `create'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
</pre>

  2) 
<pre>Micropost pages micropost creation with invalid information error messages 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button "Post" }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb__934824114_93581680'
     # ./app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___342719359_93055030'
     # ./app/controllers/concerns/microposts_controller.rb:10:in `create'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:20:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
</pre>
```

_feed.html.erb:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

home.html.erb

```
    <% if signed_in? %>
  <div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
      <section>
        <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
      </section>
      <section>
        <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
      </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="span8">
      <h3>Micropost Feed</h3>
      <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
```

microposts_controller.rb

```
    class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []      
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

micropost_pages_spec.rb

```
    require 'spec_helper'

describe "Micropost pages" do

  subject { page }

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { sign_in user }

  describe "micropost creation" do
    before { visit root_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do

      it "should not create a micropost" do
        expect { click_button "Post" }.not_to change(Micropost, :count)
      end

      describe "error messages" do
        before { click_button "Post" }
        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do

      before { fill_in 'micropost_content', with: "Lorem ipsum" }
      it "should create a micropost" do
        expect { click_button "Post" }.to change(Micropost, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

static_pages_conroller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

def home
if signed_in?
@micropost = current_user.microposts.build
@feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
end

def about
end

def help
end

def contact
end

end
```

It's my first posting on stackoverflow. Sorry if doing some mistakes
Ask questions if u need more information. I recieved this errors in ch. 10.3.3 Harlt's Rails Tutorial

Comment: Have you compared your code to the reference code https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4

Comment: What about your static controller home action? It should define `@feed_items`

Comment: add static_pages_conroller.rb with home action

Comment: the error isn't coming from the static pages controller- `/app/controllers/concerns/microposts_controller.rb:10:in 'create'`.

Comment: something's wrong in your folder structure - your MicropostsController shouldn't be in the `concerns` folder and the line the error is pointing to is line 10, which is `@feed_items = []`?

Comment: @sevenseacat thank's a lot! Now I have 5 another Failures, but I think it's not a problem :)

Comment: I have 2 micropost_controller.rb  I delete one, which was in concerns. Example of new errors, which I have now:
  5) Authentication authorization in the Microposts controller submitting to the destroy action 
     Failure/Error: before { delete micropost_path(FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)) }
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       uninitialized constant MicropostsController
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:135:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: Solved, I have misspelled the name of the file micropost_controller... Thanks @ sevenseacat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was 2 microposts_controller.rb , one of them in folder app/controllers/concerns
File wich was in app/controllers/ - misspelled.